# How to convert Date to CRM date formate?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

While working with date field, I got a date value like `/Date(1360879200000)/`. So I have used some code to get date value:

```
var mills = parseInt(rowDate.substring(6, 19));
    var date = new Date(mills);
```

here `rowDate="/Date(1360879200000)/"`, and after using this code I got a date value like `date="Fri Feb 15 03:30:00 UTC+0530 2013"`.

I have added this value to textbox.

Now , if I do some value changes in this field, how to convert this date value to CRM supported vale.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really need more information here as the question is quite vague. I'm guessing it's JavaScript judging by the parseInt function. Have you retrieved this data using oData? Or are you reading a control on the form? Are you going through the Xrm.page to get this data? If not then any reason why not?

Comment: Yes Conor, I retrieved this data using oData.
No, Can't use Xrm.Page, its a HTML web resource.

Comment: @TamalKantiDey Yes you can. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I just smacked up my CRM and I'm doing the following to my *Contact* form (no conversion to the integer at all). I'm born in February but wish to be January child.

```javascript
var control = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("birthdate");
var birthDate;
if(control){
  control.getValue();
}
alert(birthDate);

var fakeDate = new Date(birthDate.toString().replace("Feb", "Jan"));
alert(fakeDate);
```

EDIT:

You can access `Xrm.Page` from a web resource by `window.parent.Xrm.Page.etc`.

Comment: Hi Konrad,I was creating a Html web resource,using Odata I have retrieved `ScheduledEnd` value of `Task` entity. I guess,Xrm.Page can't help me in this case.

Comment: I've only used `Xrm.Page` for accessing the controls and data on the form. oData is used when you contact the server (internally e.g.) to fetch some data. But I'm not saying you're wrong, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work arround...I had time from CRM like`/Date(1360879200000)/`, from that I got year,month,day,hour,minute and second values.  with those values I made the date separated by `"-"`. Now while editing I have sent the date value to this following function. I came to know that CRM excepts date formate like: `2011-07-20T16:30:00Z`. And its working for me.

```
function dateToCRMFormat(date) {
    ///<summary>
    /// function to formate normal date value to CRM supported value
    ///</summary>

    //debugger;

    if (date!="") {
        var DateArray = date.split("-");
        var year = DateArray[0];

        var monthInt = parseInt(DateArray[1], 10);
        var month = "";
        if (monthInt < 10) {
            month = "0" + monthInt.toString();
        } else {
            month = monthInt.toString();
        }

        var dayInt = parseInt(DateArray[2], 10);
        var day = "";
        if (dayInt < 10) {
            day = "0" + dayInt.toString();
        } else {
            day = dayInt.toString();
        }
        if (DateArray[3].length == 1) {
            DateArray[3] = "0" + DateArray[3];
        }
        if (DateArray[4].length == 1) {
            DateArray[4] = "0" + DateArray[4];
        }
        if (DateArray[5].length == 1) {
            DateArray[5] = "0" + DateArray[5];
        }
        var fullDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + DateArray[3] + ":" + DateArray[4] + ":" + DateArray[5] + "Z";
        return fullDate;

    }

}
```

Anyways, I am still waiting for a real solution.

Comment: Why not use the one I suggested? Using the string representation to get a new *Date* object...

Comment: Hi Konrad,It didn't worked for me.As I am still searching for another solution, I will give it another shot.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why it didn't work? It seems to get the conversion right on both the machines I've tested it on...